# Why My Simple RecyclerView not showing anything on screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My App is just shows an Empty Screen and just the action bar, `recyclerView` is not showing anything or is not working but there are no compile time or run time errors.
It would be great help if I get an answer

Here is My MainActivity , Adapter , DataClass and Dependencies

**MainActivity (kotlin)**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

          val actionBar = supportActionBar
          actionBar!!.title = "Home"

          var mydataset = listOf<HomeData>(
              HomeData(R.drawable.cover1),
              HomeData(R.drawable.cover2),
              HomeData(R.drawable.cover3),
              HomeData(R.drawable.cover1),
              HomeData(R.drawable.cover2),
              HomeData(R.drawable.cover3),
          )

          val recycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view1)
          recycler.adapter = ItemAdapter(mydataset)
          recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }
}
```

**ItemAdapter (Kotlin)**

```
class ItemAdapter(private val dataset: List<HomeData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

          val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
              .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false)
          return ViewHolder(layout)
      }

      override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
          val item = dataset[position]
          holder.imgView.setImageResource(item.drawableResId)
      }

      override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size

      class ViewHolder(var view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
          var imgView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
      }
  
}
```

**HomeData (Kotlin)**

```
data class HomeData (@DrawableRes val drawableResId : Int)
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {

        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

        implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0"
        implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

  }
```

P.S. Its my first time asking question on StackOverflow and I tried my best to format and give necessary details.

Comment: Before set adapter add `val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Adding layoutManager to your recylerView.

The **LayoutManager** most interesting part of a RecyclerView. This object tells the RecyclerView when to recycle objects that have transitioned off-screen and where they can go. This was formerly done solely by the ListView. This feature has been separated from the RecyclerView to allow for a variety of layouts: vertical, horizontal, grid, phased, or your own!

**LinearLayoutManager** arranges objects in a way that resembles a regular ListView.

**GridLayoutManager**, like a GridView, arranges objects in a grid style.

**StaggeredGridLayoutManager** arranges items in a staggered grid format.

You can add layoutmanager something like below

```
var linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recycler.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
```